# How to to do socket programming in titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I did socket programming in phone gap using plugin .Now I am  using titanium so I need some example so that I can understand well .I have my Socket Server Ip(where my exc file is running from there I want to fetch data from server).I have also port number.

Answer (score 0):

With the Ti.Network.Socket.TCP
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.Socket.TCP

There are also code examples on that page as well.